# Converting a looped INSERT.. ON CONFLICT to a wCTE in postgres

Tags: postgresql, performance, cte, query-performance

I have an events table:

```
       Column        |            Type             |   Modifiers
---------------------+-----------------------------+---------------
 ts                  | timestamp without time zone |
 event_type          | character varying           |
 id                  | bigint                      |
 dimension_1         | integer                     |
 dimension_2         | bigint                      |
 metric_1            | bigint                      |
 metric_2            | bigint                      |
 processed           | boolean                     |
```

And various dimension tables, with a schema like:

```
       Column        |            Type             |   Modifiers
---------------------+-----------------------------+---------------
 ts                  | timestamp without time zone |
 id                  | bigint                      |
 dimension_1         | integer                     |
 dimension_2         | bigint                      |
 metric_1            | bigint                      |
 metric_2            | bigint                      |

       Column        |            Type             |   Modifiers
---------------------+-----------------------------+---------------
 ts                  | timestamp without time zone |
 id                  | bigint                      |
 dimension_1         | integer                     |
 dimension_2         | bigint                      |
 metric_2            | bigint                      |
```

Where the metrics are aggregated in some way (either by timestamp+id+dimension, or by filters etc).

The inserting from the events table -> dimension tables is currently handled by a plsql function which just does:

```
LOCK events;

FOR item in SELECT * FROM events WHERE processed=false
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO 
            dimension_table (...) 
        VALUES 
            (item.ts, item.id, item.dimension_1, item.metric_1, item.metric_2)
        ON CONFLICT 
            (ts, id, dimension_1 /* or similar */) 
        DO UPDATE
        SET 
            metric_1 = greatest(EXCLUDED.metric_1, dimension_table.metric_1), 
            metric_2 = dimension_table.metric_2 + EXCLUDED.metric_2;
    END LOOP;

UPDATE events SET processed=true;
```

I'm sure this could be done far more efficiently, and I was hoping to get some pointers as to how. Yes, the table can be locked during the insert-fanout process.

In terms of query volumes, the events table usually gets a peak of 400-500k writes/sec.

Comment: 500k writes per second? That's  30M / min. How you *did* you lock the table like you display? Your description doesn't seem right - at least incomplete. And the code you display is incomplete as well.  `max(item.z)` doesn't make sense, `pkey_column` is nowhere in your table definition, target columns of `INSERT` are missing. Please provide a working, clear example.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: The table is filled  by a process which gets events from a queue which will continue filling while the table is locked (i.e, backpressure at various levels). We can notify the fillers to back off, which will give us the ability to acquire a lock. Fixed example.

Comment: You cannot UPDATE  `metric_1` *and* `metric_2` in the same statement, since the columns are not in the same table. Please present a coherent question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Fixed. I added metric_2 to one of the example tables.